# Geofence doesn't fire for Iphone devices in XCode Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, geofencing

I'm a little confused as to why geofence isn't firing for any device other than the iPhone 5 in the simulator. Is this a bug in XCode Version 6.3.2 or an issue with my code? Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class DirectionsViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

var map: MKMapView?
var manager: CLLocationManager?
var destination: MKMapItem?

convenience init(frame:CGRect, destination:MKMapItem){
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.destination = destination
    self.view.frame = frame

    self.map = MKMapView(frame: frame)
    self.map!.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(self.map!)

    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager!.delegate = self
    manager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager!.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.map?.showsUserLocation = true
    map!.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: true)
        }

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {  
if region is CLCircularRegion {
   println("Entered")

        }
  func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {  
    var center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = destination!.placemark.coordinate
    var radius: CLLocationDistance = CLLocationDistance(300)
    var identifier: String = "Destination"
    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)
    manager?.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
        }
```

Comment: Location simulation works both in iOS Simulator and on a real device. However, iOS Simulator can be quite inaccurate in this case; the timings of the triggered events do not coincide very well with the visual movement of the simulated location in and out of each geofence. You would do better to simulate locations on your device, or better still, take the app for a walk!

Comment: yea me and walking dont get along so i'll just assume its right lol

Comment: in this case take it for a drive ;)